# How can i achieve reflections like this?

Tags: opengl, algorithm, reflection

I was in my elevator when i saw this... [image]

As you can see here that reflections are kind of stretched. What causes this? And how can we achieve something like this in computer graphics?

Comment: That is an anisotropic specular reflection (dominant in 1 direction), an effect usually from brushed metals.

Comment: check here > http://sungsoo.github.io/papers/brdf-mdf.pdf